# How to use JUnit to test the result of SAX parser?

Tags: xml, junit

I created an XML parser to parse some xml configuration files. The result of the parser is return in a callback listener, looks like this:

```
interface OnParseResultListener {
    void onFinished(Result result);
}
```

And the parser is used to get the Result object by passing in the xml file path and the listener:

```
MyParser parser = new MyParser();
parser.parse("conf.xml", new OnParseResultListener(){
    void onFinished(Result result) {
        // get the Result object here
    }
});
```

Now I want to write JUnit code to test whether MyParser is functioning well. But when I put the above code in a test method, the test method was always terminated before `onFinished()` was invoked.

I tried to use `wait()` after calling `parse()`, and use `notify()` in `onFinished()` when parsing is done, but it waited forever. My guess is that the JUnit thread is blocked, but the SAX XMLReader needs to send events to that thread, so it won't get through.

So I cannot block the JUnit thread but it ends before my parsing is done.. What can I do to test the parsing result??

MyParser looks roughly like this:

```
public class MyParser {
    OnParserResultListener listener;
    public void parse(InputStream xml, OnParserResultListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser;
        try {
            parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xmlReader = parser.getXMLReader();

            //handle xml parsing events in a customized BaseHandler
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(new BaseHandler());

            InputSource is = new InputSource(xml);
            xmlReader.parse(is);
        } catch (Exception e) {} 
    }
}

class BaseHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    public void startElement(String u, String l, String q, Attributes a) {
        .... //handle xml tag
    }

    public void endElement(String r, String l, String q) throws SAXException {
        .... //read xml value, save to a Result object

        //return the Result object via OnParserResultListener's callback method
        this.listener.onFinished(Result);
    }
    ....//other methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a locking mechanism inside the callback to put the calling thread on hold while the results are being delivered.

You also want to timeout your test in the event that the callback is never fired.  Something like the following should work:

```
@Test(timeout = 5000) 
public void receivesResultsFromParser() {
    final Semaphore latch = new Semaphore(1);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           MyParser parser = new MyParser(); 
           parser.parse("conf.xml", new OnParseResultListener(){
               void onFinished(Result result) {
                   // do result validation here
                   latch.release();
               }
           });
        }
     }).start();

     latch.acquire();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MrWiggles, but adding Semaphore didn't help to solve this. Because Semaphore.acquire() blocks the JUnit thread, so that onFinished() was never invoked, until the test was timeout and terminated. Because in MyParser I used XMLReader to parse the XML, I think if the JUnit thread was blocked, XMLReader stopped working.

Comment: My bad, I assumed your parser was running in a different thread.  Take the approach above and execute the parser in a separate thread.  The Semaphore will ensure the text then waits for completion.  I've updated the code

Comment: Hi @MrWiggles, using a thread has the same problem. Because MyParser.parse() does not block the thread, and it takes some time to finish parsing, but the run() method ends and the thread stops right after MyParser.parse() is invoked, so onFinished () of OnParseResultListener can never callback.

Comment: It might be useful for you to share the code of MyParser